# read a xml file with Jdom

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to browse a xml file with JDOM. 
and here the xml file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"  encoding= "UTF-8" ?> 
<definitions name="Web Service Mediation"
targetNamespace="http://these-info.univ-tun.com/Web Service Mediation" 
xmlns="http://these-info.univ-tun.comstem online" >
<binding name="ConnTWS" type="wsdlns:SimplePortType">
<soap:binding   style="rpc"  transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="soap">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/action/binding.ConnTWS"/>
</operation>
</binding>  
</definitions>
```

But when I run the class .java, I would have the following errors:

```
org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 6 of document file:/C:/Users/samsung/Desktop/copie%20de%20workspace/PluginFinal/plugin/eclipsehelio%20avec%20atl%20-%20Copie/workspace/Jdom2/Grammaire.xml: The prefix "soap" for element "soap:binding" is not bound.
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:465)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:810)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:789)
    at JDOM.main(JDOM.java:24)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "soap" for element "soap:binding" is not bound.
```

Anyone can help to correct the xml file.
Thank you very much .

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared soap namespace. Add `xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"` to your definitions attributes. Like this:

```
<definitions name="Web Service Mediation"
 targetNamespace="http://these-info.univ-tun.com/Web Service Mediation" 
 xmlns="http://these-info.univ-tun.comstem online" 
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
```